# eclipse plugin/application writing into an cvs file

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

so I am making a software for the eclipse, that tracks the changes made by the user, I have all the data available but now I need to put it into a cvs file located somewhere in the project folder, as the program should be able to be used by anyone without changing the file path.

ps the normal file path works, so I know that the code is alright, just don't seem to be able to print in the project folder.

```
try {
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("logger.csv"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            
            sb.append("time");
            sb.append(",");
            sb.append("action");
            sb.append(",");
            sb.append("info");
            sb.append("\n");
            
            sb.append("17:00");
            sb.append(",");
            sb.append("create");
            sb.append(",");
            sb.append("test");
            sb.append("\n");
            
            sb.append("17:40");
            sb.append(",");
            sb.append("del");
            sb.append(",");
            sb.append("test2");
            sb.append("\n");
            
            pw.write(sb.toString());
            pw.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

From an Eclipse plug-in you should use Eclipse's resource API to make sure resource changes are synchronized with the workspace:

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspace;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspaceRoot;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.ICoreRunnable;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.NullProgressMonitor;

public class Foo {

    public void bar() throws CoreException {
        IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
        workspace.run((ICoreRunnable) monitor -> {
            IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();
            IProject project = root.getProject("projectName");
            IFile csv = project.getFile("logger.csv");
            InputStream initialContent = new ByteArrayInputStream("time,action".getBytes());
            csv.create(initialContent, true, new NullProgressMonitor());
        });
    }

}
```

See also [Eclipse Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Resources), [Vogella](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseResources/article.html) and the [Javadoc](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIResource.html) for further details.